# Query related to parse push notification

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, schedule

I would like to know what does "Send the push at this time in each user's respective timezone" mean while I am setting up scheduled push notifications in Parse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you schedule the push, for example, to 8PM and request to "Send the push at this time in each user's respective timezone", then each user would get the push at 8PM local time (based on that user's timezone).

Comment: Thanks for your response. That means if I am checking that checkbox and setting time as 8PM IST, the guy in UK will get it at 8MP UK time

Comment: @hellosachin77 That's what it implies.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.